# Ninject Alter Binding base on Owin.Context.User.Identy

Tags: ninject, owin, ninject.web.mvc, owin-middleware, ninject.web

I need to change ninject binding base on User.Identity.

I have this scenario:
 base on user Actor claim which I use for my own purpose.
 I have to inject on my class constructor the value of Claims.Actor, 
how can I do that?

```
public class C { 
    public C (string ActorValue) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy, if i understood the requirement correctly:

```
kernel.Bind<C>().ToMethod(
            ctx =>
              {
                // you can also do anything like HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext() etc..
                var id = HttpContext.Current?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "not found";
                return new C(id);
              });
```